# Fail time with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=6e^{-x}e^{-2y}, \quad 0<x<y< \infty$

Tags: actuarial-science

The following is the problem I am solving for.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be the fail time for a machine with two components.  The component $Y$ will start working if and only if component $X$ fails.  The machine fails when component $Y$ fails as well.  Given the joint density function
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=6e^{-x}e^{-2y}, \quad 0<x<y< \infty$$
>
> find the expected time of failure of the machine.

My method was to find

$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_x^{\infty} (x+y)6e^{-x}e^{-2y} dydx$$

which ended up being equal to $ 7 \over 6$.

However, the answer was supposedly approximately 0.83.

I am not quite sure how to solve this problem.

Can someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: The expected time of failure of the machine is E(Y), not E(X+Y).

Comment: Hello, Did.  That's the part I am not understanding.  If Component Y starts moving after component X does, then the time until complete failure would be X+Y, would it not?

Comment: No, it would not. Quote: "Let X and Y be the fail time for a machine with two components". Thus Y is the fail time of component Y, hence also the fail time of the machine itself.

Comment: But Y starts after X, right?  So if Y=2, for example, under the situation X=1 then the fail time would be 3.  But if X=4 then the fail time would be 6.

Comment: @hyg17, Use the fact that$0\lt x\lt y\lt \infty$.  There will never be a time when x=4 and y = 2.  If Y = y, it will find the marginal distribution of Y by integrating from 0 to y.  That is how you are taking care of the fact that fail time of X is factored in.  Now for the machine to fail, it is only Y that you will have to take care. Expected time will be $\int y.f(y)$.

Comment: I guess I get it a bit more.  I'm worried that the next time I see this I won't be able to understand it, but I kind of get this one at least.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

The answer is not approximately 0.83, but $\frac{5}{6}$.  Use the following formulation  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{y} (y)(6e^{-x}e^{-2y})dxdy$$.  A tedious integration by parts and you will land up with the answer $\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: ?? But 5/6 is approximately 0.83, no?

Comment: Yes Sir, when I calculated it was $\frac{5}{6}$ exact a round fraction and then I typed out my result.  Then I realised he could have approximated it. Hands down defeat!!. Sorry